# How to set the DataType of a Vaadin7 Grid after it was created

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm using the Vaadin-7 Designer to create a Grid that should contain several columns, some of which are not String.

When I try to add a Row that contains a non-String element I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 0(4711) is not an instance of java.lang.String
at com.vaadin.ui.Grid.addRow(Grid.java:6821)
```

How do I provide the Grid with the information that the Column is meant to be an Integer?

As I have no influence over the constructor (its called by the designer) I need a solution that doesn't use one (or shows how to apply the new object to the designer or similar afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the grid you can try to define your Integer column like this:

```
grid.addColumn("Column_Name", Integer.class);
```

You must do this before using the grid (adding rows).

Another way is to use BeanItemContainer. This code from Vadding documantation for the grid:

```
// Have some data
Collection<Person> people = Lists.newArrayList(
    new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 1543),
    new Person("Galileo Galilei", 1564),
    new Person("Johannes Kepler", 1571));

 // Have a container of some type to contain the data
BeanItemContainer<Person> container =
new BeanItemContainer<Person>(Person.class, people);

// Create a grid bound to the container
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
grid.setColumnOrder("name", "born");
layout.addComponent(grid);
```

For more information:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-grid.html

Good Luck!

Comment: I'll try try the first approach. The second adds the new Grid to some container, but then I'll loose the configuration already done in designer.

Comment: I don't know what kind of container you are using. Another solution will be to get the container from the grid and add the column to the container. Maybe it will work. Define the properties (columns) container.addContainerProperty("name", Integer.class, "noname");

Comment: It seems the Columns are already strictly typed when I try to change them, so I get errors on that too. This Designer is so clumsy...

Comment: Haha, ok If you want you can try to get all of the existing columns make a new container copy them create your new column and set the new container on the place of the old one. I hope this will work.